# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.7:run (default-cli) on project userms:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to run a maven application using spring on running the application compiles successfully but on running the command mvn spring-boot:run the following error appears.
I am running the application in eclipse IDE.

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.7:run (default-cli) on project userms: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

This is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.trainingapps</groupId>
    <artifactId>userms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>userms</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.29</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId> <!-- or jjwt-gson if Gson is preferred -->
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This error never occured before when I was running other applications.

Comment: The error you provided ("Failed to execute goal...") is just saying that the Maven goal failed because the application quit. You need to look at and provide the logs from your Spring Boot application to see why the application exited.

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake I had typed wrong password in application.properties

Comment: Guys I really appreciate i spent 3 months fixing thins but this answer fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Hi the issue can be cause by a lot of things but the funny thing could be small typing mistake in application.properties.

in my case I missed out one letter in the database name and in his case he gave the application a wrong password.

Check letter by letter and line by line.

Comment: very unlikely to be a problem in application properties since this file is read at runtime and this error is compile time

Comment: Well... when you run "mvn spring-boot:run"  the application tries to run, as the command implies, so the properties file WILL get read.